# Why is my request to the Strapi change-password api not working?

Tags: javascript, strapi, change-password

I'm unable to get the Strapi change-password api working (using latest version 4.4.1). The following code returns a 400 - Bad Request.

```
async function changePassword() {
  fetchURL = `${dbPath}api/auth/change-password`;
  fetchHeader = new Headers();
  fetchHeader.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${jwtString}`);
  fetchHeader.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  fetchCommand = new Request(fetchURL, { 
    method: "POST", 
    headers: fetchHeader, 
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "data": {
        "currentPassword": oldPasswordInput.value,
        "password": newPasswordInput.value,
        "passwordConfirmation": confirmPasswordInput.value
      }})
   })
  try {
    response = await fetch(fetchCommand);
    if (response.ok) {
      data = await response.json();
      writeLogRecord(userId, 0, 0, "Password change successful");
      modalText.innerText = "Password successfully changed";
      displayModalContainer();
    } else {
      modalText.innerText = "Password not changed";
      displayModalContainer();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("User Fetch error", err);
  }
}
```

Chrome console shows me this:
POST http://localhost:1337/api/auth/change-password 400 (Bad Request)

I've looked on both the Strapi Discord and Strapi forums but have found no help.

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong?

(Added 10/3/2022)
The Strapi docs show how to do this via axios:

```
axios.post(
  'http://localhost:1337/api/auth/change-password',
  {
    currentPassword: 'currentPassword',
    password: 'userNewPassword',
    passwordConfirmation: 'userNewPassword',
  },
  {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer <user jwt token>',
    },
  }
);
```

Updated JS

```
async function changePassword() {
  fetchURL = `${dbPath}api/auth/change-password`;
  fetchHeader = new Headers();
  fetchHeader.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${jwtString}`);
  fetchHeader.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
  fetchCommand = new Request(fetchURL, { 
    method: "POST", 
    headers: fetchHeader, 
    body: JSON.stringify({
        currentPassword: oldPasswordInput.value,
        password: newPasswordInput.value,
        passwordConfirmation: confirmPasswordInput.value
      })
   })
  try {
    response = await fetch(fetchCommand);
    if (response.ok) {
      data = await response.json();
      modalText.innerText = "Password successfully changed";
      displayModalContainer();
    } else {
      modalText.innerText = "Password not changed";
      displayModalContainer();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("User Fetch error", err);
  }
```

Still returns POST http://localhost:1337/api/auth/change-password 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: Are you sure the body being sent is in the correct format?

Comment: You are wrapping your body in `data`, that's probably what's wrong.

Comment: @evolutionxbox - I believe so. The Strapi docs show how to do this via axios - I've put that into my question - I believe I've copied the intent of that in JS.

Comment: @CherryDT - I'm not sure why I had the data clause in there. I took it out, but it still gives me the same error - I've modified my original question to show the code as how it looks now.

Answer (score 0):

And I figured this out - posting in case anyone else runs into this. Below is the correct way to format the payload of this request. The data tag is necessary, but it and the field names should not be in quotes. Note this is a modification to my original post, not the second one I tried.

```
data: {
  currentPassword: currentPasswordInput.value,
  password: newPasswordInput.value,
  passwordConfirmation: confirmPasswordInput.value
```